# Flip with different div for eack button click not working

Tags: jquery, flip, flippy

I have a div its content should be changed(from the content of another div) with a flip depending on the button click 
**here is my code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jqueryflippy/jquery.flippy.min.js"></script>
<style>
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #757575; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%, #707070 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#757575), color-stop(100%,#707070)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#757575', endColorstr='#707070',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}


.content{
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    left:20%;   
    height:40%;
    width:60%;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;      
}

.contentTitle{
    height:15%;
    width:100%;
    color:#ffffff;      
    font-size:15px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #2d2d2d; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%, #7d7e7d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2d2d2d), color-stop(100%,#7d7e7d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2d2d2d', endColorstr='#7d7e7d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
.contentBody{
    height:85%;
    width:100%;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){   
    $("#content").hide();
    $("#content").animate({opacity:"show"},2000);
});
function rotate(divId){ 
    alert(divId);
        $(".content").flippy({
            content : $('#'+divId).clone(true, true),
            direction : "TOP",
            duration : "2000",
            onStart : function() {
                //alert("Let's flip");
            },
            onFinish : function() {
                //alert("ok, it's flipped :)");

            }
        });

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content" id="div1">

        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div1 Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentBody">
            <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div2')"/>
        </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="content" id="div2" style="visibility:hidden;">

        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div2 Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentBody">
            <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div3')"/>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content" id="div3" style="visibility:hidden;">

        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div3 Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentBody">
            <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div1')"/>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But after first flip(its working correctly) the button click giving the same div content(that is div2).
    I have been stuck with this for a day any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please find working code ahead.

Reason for error : you are using .content class in every div flipped, that is on the first time flippy changes all div with class .content to div2.

Check below working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creating Popup Div | istockphp.com</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<style>
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #757575; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%, #707070 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#757575), color-stop(100%,#707070)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #757575 0%,#707070 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#757575', endColorstr='#707070',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}


.content{
    position:relative;
    top:30%;
    left:20%;   
    height:40%;
    width:60%;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;      
}

.contentTitle{
    height:15%;
    width:100%;
    color:#ffffff;      
    font-size:15px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #2d2d2d; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%, #7d7e7d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2d2d2d), color-stop(100%,#7d7e7d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2d2d2d 0%,#7d7e7d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2d2d2d', endColorstr='#7d7e7d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
.contentBody{
    height:85%;
    width:100%;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/jquery.flippy.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){   
        //$("#content").hide();
        $("#content").animate({opacity:"show"},2000);
    });
    function getHtml(divId) {
        var cont = $('#'+divId).html();
        alert(cont);
        return cont;
    }
    function rotate(divId){ 
        alert(divId);
        $(".content").flippy({
            content : getHtml(divId),
            direction : "TOP",
            duration : "500",
            //verso : "test 1",
            onStart : function() {
                //alert("Let's flip");
            },
            onFinish : function() {
                //alert("ok, it's flipped :)");

            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="contentTitle">
        <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div1 Details</div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentBody">
        <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div2')"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden;">

        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div1 Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentBody">
            <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div2')"/>
        </div>

    </div>  

    <div id="div2" style="visibility:hidden;">

        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div2 Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentBody">
            <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div3')"/>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="div3" style="visibility:hidden;">

        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div style="padding:1% 0 0 0;">div3 Details</div>
        </div>

        <div class="contentBody">
            <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="rotate('div1')"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks,once div3 is shown it doesn't go back to div1 on click

Comment: sorry, i forgot that div1 is also replaced with last flip, so you need to remove .content class from it too.. also you need to create another div with class .content so that flipping can be done on it.. i have updated the code.. please recopy and check.